# Get cursor position on scroll zoom image

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the x,y coordinates on a click in a JPG image.
When just clicking the image I can get the coordinates, but I have a scroll zoom on the image and when zoomed the image is draggable. So when I drag the image after zooming and click to get the coordinates it is completely different.
I need the exact x,y coordinate of the click inside the image, not on the page.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?
It can be in javascript, jquery
I am using http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/ to zoom the jpg.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow us to help you more efficiently (consider compiling your codes in a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net))

Comment: I can't get it running on jfiddle, but you can take a look at http://www.laenen-it.be/test

Let's say I want the xy coordinates of Paris in France. It works when zoomed out, but when I use scroll zoom and drag the image, the coordinates of Paris are different.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I've used a different zoom plugin (outer zoom) instead.
So now the original jpg doesn't have to be dragged and the coordinates are always correct.

Comment: Please, add some details like what is the name of the library, link to download/read about it. Thanks!

Comment: The plugin I used to zoom can be found here: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/02/magnificent-js-jquery-responsive-zoom-image-plugin/

To get the coordinates:
var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;